# Android: Volley Timeout crash Fix

Tags: android, timeout, android-volley, connection-timeout, acra

My application crashes(Once in a while) with this com.android.volley.TimeoutError.
Below you can see the stack_trace and the logcat outputs.

I already have an error handling function like below:

```
private Response.ErrorListener volleyErrorListener = new Response.ErrorListener({
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
        stopLoader();
        showToast(Constant.ERROR);
    }
};
```

(I thought this will handle all the events like timeouts, no connectivity, etc.)

1. Could you kindly explain why this is happening?
2. How can I prevent my app from crashing? (any sample codes will be appreciated)

Thanks in advance!

```
ANDROID_VERSION=4.3
PHONE_MODEL=GT-I9300
```

**STACK_TRACE**

```
com.android.volley.TimeoutError
at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:123)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

**LOGCAT**

```
04-02 18:11:18.405 I/dalvikvm(21976): Could not find method com.google.inject.Injector.getTypeConverterBindings, referenced from method roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.getTypeConverterBindings
04-02 18:11:18.405 W/dalvikvm(21976): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 27646: Lcom/google/inject/Injector;.getTypeConverterBindings ()Ljava/util/Set;
04-02 18:11:18.405 D/dalvikvm(21976): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x000c
04-02 18:11:18.560 D/dalvikvm(21976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 884K, 18% free 9573K/11636K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 29ms
04-02 18:11:18.560 D/dalvikvm(21976): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
04-02 18:11:18.655 D/dalvikvm(21976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 932K, 18% free 9647K/11760K, paused 2ms+9ms, total 28ms
04-02 18:11:18.715 D//Ln.java:218(21976): main Configuring Logging, minimum log level is INFO
04-02 18:11:18.850 I/System.out(21976): Logged In-> null
04-02 18:11:18.880 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:18.885 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:18.885 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:18.890 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:18.935 D/libEGL  (21976): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-02 18:11:18.945 D/libEGL  (21976): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-02 18:11:18.950 D/libEGL  (21976): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-02 18:11:18.960 E/        (21976): Device driver API match
04-02 18:11:18.960 E/        (21976): Device driver API version: 23
04-02 18:11:18.960 E/        (21976): User space API version: 23 
04-02 18:11:18.960 E/        (21976): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
04-02 18:11:19.065 D/OpenGLRenderer(21976): Enabling debug mode 0
04-02 18:11:19.090 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:19.090 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:19.090 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:19.095 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:27.845 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:27.850 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:28.255 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:28.255 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:28.750 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:28.755 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:29.770 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:29.775 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:30.260 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:30.260 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:30.675 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:30.680 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:31.020 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:31.020 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:31.180 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:31.185 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:33.500 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:33.500 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:34.640 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:36.705 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:36.755 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.140 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.140 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.610 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.615 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.885 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.885 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:37.925 D/dalvikvm(21976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1226K, 20% free 9832K/12240K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 32ms
04-02 18:11:38.370 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:38.375 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:38.925 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:39.200 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:39.245 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:39.450 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:39.455 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:39.845 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:39.850 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.355 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.360 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.395 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.685 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.685 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.685 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:42.710 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.070 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.070 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.070 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.095 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.445 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.445 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.445 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.480 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.840 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.840 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.840 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:43.885 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:44.225 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:44.225 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:44.230 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:44.260 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:44.830 D/ProgressBar(21976): setProgress = 0
04-02 18:11:44.830 D/ProgressBar(21976): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
04-02 18:11:44.830 D/ProgressBar(21976): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
04-02 18:11:44.875 D/dalvikvm(21976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 19% free 9969K/12240K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
04-02 18:11:44.875 I/dalvikvm-heap(21976): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.960MB for 1127536-byte allocation
04-02 18:11:44.895 D/dalvikvm(21976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 18% free 11068K/13344K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 20ms
04-02 18:11:44.895 D/dalvikvm(21976): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
04-02 18:11:44.895 D/dalvikvm(21976): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
04-02 18:11:44.960 D/ProgressBar(21976): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
04-02 18:11:44.960 D/ProgressBar(21976): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
04-02 18:11:44.960 D/ProgressBar(21976): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
04-02 18:11:44.960 D/ProgressBar(21976): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
04-02 18:11:45.745 D/TextLayoutCache(21976): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
04-02 18:11:55.635 D/ACRA    (21976): Using custom Report Fields
04-02 18:11:55.675 I/ACRA    (21976): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
04-02 18:11:55.695 D/ACRA    (21976): Retrieving logcat output...
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been encountered by same sought of issue when i started using `volley`, i downloaded `volley` from this [link](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) and later on , i realized that this is not the official source code, it was The **EDITED** one , and the editor of this source code had customized the official source code according to his own requirements.
Then i downloaded actual source of `volley` from [official google account](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) and my all issues related to `volley` are fixed now.
So download the official source code from [official google account](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley).

Comment: do inform me if you face any difficulty during downloading, i will send you jar file of library.

Comment: Thanks kashif181. How can I download the .jar file? Is there a direct link without git clone?

Comment: You can directly download source code the from this link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master by clicking tgz on this link. And then make jar file (By making library project). Otherwise you can download jar file from my drop box this is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/cl299js7yr0faz8/volleylib.jar?dl=0

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks kashift181, you helped me alot !